# binascii decoding in python 2 vs 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
python2 test.py

ascii_term_id? "0500"
```

```
python3 test.py

ascii_term_id? "b'0500'"
```

I'm trying get this function to work between python2 and 3. Python 3 seems to have extraneous data in the variable.

I'm not totally sure how this `binascii.b2a_hex` works between python versions:

```
    if os.path.isfile(C + 'file.TMP'):
        with open(C + 'file.tmp', 'rb') as eamterms:
            sector = eamterms.read(sector_size)
            while sector:
                if sector_count > 0:
                    sector = sector[4:sector_size]
                    for i in range(0, sector_size, record_size):
                        record = sector[i:record_size + i]
                        #print(str(record))
                        # Terminal ID is the key
                        term_id = record[0:2]
                        # convert it to ascii
                        ascii_term_id = binascii.b2a_hex(term_id)
                        #print(str(ascii_term_id) + " " + str(term_id))
                        # Skip nulls and the store record
                        if sector_count == 283:
                            print('ascii_term_id? "' + str(ascii_term_id) + '"')
                            print('----------------------------')
                            quit()
```

Comment: It doesn't have extranous data, but in Python 3, you are working with `bytes` objects, not a `str` object. Note, this was the *primary motivating factor* for making backward-incompatible Python 2-3 transition. You should really just stick to Python 3 from here on out, given that Python 2 is officially passed it's end of life

Comment: you get extra `b' '` because you `str(ascii_term_id)` instead of  `ascii_term_id.decode()`. On Python 3 `print(str(b'0500'))` gives `"b'0500'"` but `print(b'0500'.decode())` gives `"0500"`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga we are in the process of converting but we are still working with some legacy systems that are stuck with python2 for now. But this process is part of the process to get us off it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
ascii_term_id.decode()
```

instead of

```
str(ascii_term_id)
```

---

Code

```
print( b'0500'.decode() )
print( str(b'0500') )
```

on Python 2 gives

```
0500
0500
```

but on Python 3 gives

```
0500
b'0500'
```

---

**EDIT:**

You need only

```
print('ascii_term_id? "' + ascii_term_id.decode() + '"')
```

because `decode()` converts `bytes` to `string` (Python3) and you don't need `str()` any more.

```
ascii_term_id = b'0500'

print( type( ascii_term_id ) )
print( type( ascii_term_id.decode() ) )

print('ascii_term_id? "' + ascii_term_id.decode() + '"')
```

Python 2:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
ascii_term_id? "0500"
```

Python 3

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'str'>
ascii_term_id? "0500"
```

Comment: That got me over the hump. I just set ascii_term_id = ascii_term_id.decode() before the IF value check. Fixed everything after that. Thanks!

Comment: you need only `print('ascii_term_id? "' + ascii_term_id.decode() + '"')`. You don't have to use `str()` any more.

Comment: @MarkRansom  I'm sure - `decode()` converts `bytes` to `string` and you add two normal string. Try `print( type(ascii_term_id.decode()) )` and you see that it is string, not bytes.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Somehow I was confusing decode and encode.

Comment: @MarkRansom sometimes I have also problem with `decode`, `encode` so long time ago I made image to remeber it: [Python Unicode - decode & encode](https://blog.furas.pl/python-unicode-decode-encode.html). Page is in my native language - Polish - but image is in English.